# Update query not working and asking for substitue in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I have a query where I want to update like below

```
update tbl_fiber_inv_job_progress 
set ums_group_ass_by_id = 626,
ums_group_ass_by_name = 'Construction_Engineer',
ums_group_ass_to_id = 622,
ums_group_ass_to_name = 'O&M Fiber Engineer',  -- 
approv_reject_remark = 'Reoffered',
modified_by = 'ORA SCHEDULER',
modified_date = SYSDATE
where job_id =  32905;
```

But getting error as

> Enter value for M

Please help

Comment: Are you sure that the update query you posted above actually reproduces the problem?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: it is not allowing me to update it

Answer (score 0):

I think the cause of your problem is the & character in the next line:

```
ums_group_ass_to_name = 'O&M Fiber Engineer',
```

If you use SQLPlus try this line:

```
set define off;
```

Comment: I am using Oracle

Comment: @Nad - SQL\*Plus is an (and the original) Oracle client. Maybe you're using Oracle SQL Developer, or SQLcl, but those behave much the same and understand `set define off`. Other clients like Toad and PL/SQL Developer copy a lot of the behaviour too.

Answer (score 0):

The `&` character is used to identify substitution variables in several scripting engines like sqlplus and TOAD. You need to escape that character in the string, so that it can be interpreted correctly. Try this:

```
ums_group_ass_to_name = 'O\&M Fiber Engineer',
```

or place this command before your DML in the script:

```
set define off;
```

Comment: `'O\&M Fiber Engineer'` its giving me result as `O\&M Fiber Engineer`